# “On/over the phone”

Tags: grammar, idioms, prepositions

Which version is correct?

1. As discussed with you **over** the phone.
2. As discussed with you **on** the phone.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Either works just fine as written.  Pace @JasonChen, “on the phone” works quite as well as “over the phone” as an adverbial phrase for modifying a verb of telling, and actually [appears to have been more common since about 1957](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=told+you+on+the+phone%2Ctold+you+over+the+phone%2Ctold+you+by+phone&year_start=1911&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctold%20you%20on%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctold%20you%20over%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctold%20you%20by%20phone%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Can it be expedient to say: "to call someone with the phone"?

Comment: @Eugene, *expedience* would depend on context, considered in all its rhetorical, social, and political dimensions. But it would seem normal and natural English usage only where "the phone" refers to an individual instrument already specified--say, if you had just bought a used and reconditioned cell phone and wanted to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your having heeded my question! I have twigged it. It is like:"What can you do with an outdated landline telephone nowadays?"-"I can call my elders with the phone like that".

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context of the sentence.

You can say that you "told someone over the phone." This means that you told them using your phone. "Over the phone" is usually applied when you tell someone something.

You can also say that you are "on the phone." This means you are calling someone.

In this case, "over the phone" is correct, since you are telling the person something.